# Is it possible to load OpenFOAM solution file using ParaView Python Shell without using GUI?

Tags: python, paraview, openfoam

I have OpenFOAM solution file obtained on HPC (cluster computer system) in which I have no GUI access. I have Python code that works on Python Shell of ParaView without any problem but I need to open ParaView to use the code. I want to run this Python code on HPC and calculate some parameters using ParaView Python ability. Is it possible to do this without activating GUI of ParaView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course. You can generate a python trace in ParaView (Tools-> Start Trace). This will help you find out what code you are missing :

```
from paraview.simple import * 

casefoam = OpenFOAMReader(FileName='/path/to/case.foam')
casefoam.MeshRegions = ['internalMesh']
casefoam.CellArrays = ['U']
casefoam.CaseType = 'Decomposed Case'
```

etc....

Then you can use the pvbatch utility to run this. However, if you are going to run it on a cluster environment where the nodes don't have access to X then you need to make sure pvbatch was compiled with off-screen rendering capability using either EGL or OSMesa.